# How to close the current MDIChld form when opening a new MDIChild?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub f1btnalpha_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles f1btnalpha.Click
    Dim NewMDIChild2 As New Form2()
    'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
    NewMDIChild2.MdiParent = Me
    'Display the new form.
    NewMDIChild2.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub f1btnbeacon_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles f1btnbeacon.Click
    Dim NewMDIChild3 As New Form3()
    'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
    NewMDIChild3.MdiParent = Me
    'Display the new form.
    NewMDIChild3.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub f1btnm6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles f1btnm6.Click
    Dim NewMDIChild4 As New Form4()
    'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
    NewMDIChild4.MdiParent = Me
    'Display the new form.
    NewMDIChild4.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `MdiChildren` property is an array of all MDI child forms. You can simply loop over that and close each one:

```vb
For Each mdiChild In MdiChildren
    mdiChild.Close()
Next
```

That will handle cases of zero, one or multiple child forms.

That said, if you know that there will never be more than one child form, you can do this for a more succinct option:

```vb
MdiChildren.FirstOrDefault()?.Close()
```

`FirstOrDefault` will return the first item in the list or `Nothing` if there are no items. The `?.` operator will short-circuit if the operand is `Nothing` or call the `Close` method if there's a form to close. If you're working on the assumption that there MUST be only one form, it would be more appropriate to call `SingleOrDefault`, which will throw an exception if there are multiple child forms, letting you know of the issue rather than blindly carrying on.

If there may be multiple children but the loop is still too verbose for you, there's this option too:

```vb
Array.ForEach(MdiChildren, Sub(f) f.Close())
```